# Angular - Confirmation event to child component from parent component

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-components

**Context:**
Working on generic data table with inline edit feature.

**Components:**
data-table.component.(ts|html|css)

**Process:**
- This is a generic data table, can be used just by passing columns and    rows to display.
- It has inline edit feature for some of the cells.
- On edit complete, an event will be sent to feature component(parent).
- Business logic to handle save data is up to the feature    component(parent).

**Question:

- Save is an async process, on complete of save, how can I send confirmation response back to data table component if the save was success or fail ?**

Thanks

Comment: Please add your code and then explain what you want to do.

Comment: Using @input decorator/subject with observable, you can pass data from parent to child component.

Comment: "Save is an async process".. you did not explain where the save functionality is.. as for passing event from child to parent, you can emit object containing `rowId, columnId, currentValue, previousValue` to the parent

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by injecting the child component (datatable component) into your feature component via `@ViewChild()`, see the official documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) for an example.

I assume your feature component template contains the datatable component like so:

```
<my-datatable-component [rows]="rows" [cols]="cols"></my-datatable-component>
```

In your feature component inject your child component:

```
@ViewChild(MyDatatableComponent) myDatatableComponent: MyDatatableComponent;
```

Now you have access to your datatable component and can call a function on the component to notify it of the outcome of the save process (after the async save process has completed of course).

Comment: Since the table being developed here is a generic one, which means that it may be used by multiple components, it would be better if the table handle things on its own, rather than depending on the component which uses it.

Answer (score 0):

You define save method in you parent component which you will bind to child component and receive input in your parent component only using property bind and event emitter or rxjs subject by defining a subject in child component with editeditem property and subscribe in parent component to it